# Series when at each step angle and radius of the area of the disc is halved.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am currently studying from a lecture notes for analysis in single variable, and found interesting exercise for series that I am unsure about.

**Exercise:**  A disc with radius 1 is colored according to the pattern shown in Figure. At every step, the angle and radius of the area to be colored is halved. [Illustration for the Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghbbU.png)

**(a)** Suppose that this process is repeated an infinite number of times. Write down a series that expresses the total colored area.

So, I start with writing down potential partial sums:
$S_n = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} + \frac{\pi (r/2)^2}{4} + \frac{\pi (r/4)^2}{8} + \cdots$. Thus obtaining $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \pi \frac{(r/2^{n-1})^2}{2^n}$$
Is this seems to be the right representation of this sum or am I missing something?

**(b)** Compute the sum of the series you found in **(a)**.

Here, yet, I am not sure how to proceed. I know that this sum converges, but I am unable to compute exact value for the series on my own. I tried to approximate by Python and got 2.6214658... and I suppose series should be equal to $\frac{4\pi r^2}{7}$ (As WolframAlpha suggested). Could someone, please suggest the right way to deal with such sum and how to find its value.

It's my first post on the MSE so, I would be thankful for any suggestions on what to correct etc. Thanks

Comment: question b) it is a geometric series : therefore there is a **formula** helping to get rid of the $\Sigma$. This is why you have finally such a simple result...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. Is it $\frac{a}{1-r}$, for $r<1$, right?

Comment: yes @NoamMann . Are you able to find $a$ and $r$ here?

Comment: also, it's $|r|<1$, but since here $r$ is positive, it's of no real trouble.

Comment: Yes. Of course, the $r$ of the formula and the $r$ of the radius arnot the same...

Comment: Thanks, I do understand. Now just trying to move things around and figure out the problem.

Comment: Therefore, the appropriate version of this series should be $\sum \frac{4 \pi r^2}{8^n}$, right?